# Setting up openstack (devstack install) on Soft layer Bare Metal

Tags: openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, devstack

I am looking for help on steps for setting up devstack on Softlayer bare metal. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next link is a script that uses Git to install Devstack on a SoftLayer Ubuntu bare metal server.
https://gist.github.com/amfred/2573ecabcb7c868b120a

Here you can find additional information on SoftLayer Object Storage.
http://blog.softlayer.com/tag/openstack

http://blog.mist.io/post/73402239574/set-up-your-own-openstack-havana-in-10-minutes

The next refers to installing Devstack on a SoftLayer Cloud Compute Instance.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/8160eff1-dedf-408e-9395-9dffeb68749f?tags=devstack&lang=en